# ExternalIP for Kubernetes service

Tags: kubernetes

I wanted some help in understanding the ExternalIP field in Kubernetes services.
Based on the information https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#external-ips
I understood that I can define a Kubernetes service and assign a Ip address using the ExternalIP field.
To test this i created a Kubernetes environment on AWS using Rancher. In the Kubernetes cluster, i deployed a image and created a Nodeport service and assigned a ElasticIp to the Nodeport service. 
My expectation was that i will be able to access the service using the ElasticIP:Nodeport.

However the there is no response. I am getting the error destination not available.

If i run the command

```
kubectl get svc -n namepace
```

I could see the ElasticIP under the elastic ip field.

I then deployed the same service without the ExternalIp field. This time the Nodeport service. I could access the deployment using the Nodeipaddress:Nodeport.

Comment: Did you attach the external ip to the node ?

Comment: Yes, i tried that also. That didn't work either

Comment: I think attaching external ip to the node should work. Check if incoming traffic is allowed on the node on port `Nodeport` in firewall / security group settings.

Comment: Because if I remember correctly by default all incoming traffic is blocked on AWS.

Comment: That is on the vpc. Ip address has no rules. The node is accessible by its own ip address.I will try the same configuration on a on Prem deployment. Will try there. So if i assign the external ip to the node there, the issue where service will not be accessible when the node is dead , will still exist right?

Comment: I think you need to use service `--type=LoadBalancer` and then use the Public IP of your node and port of it is exposed to the outside world i.e 80:32753. so For example 54.214.214.156:32753.

Comment: Yes. As Aamir said, ideally you should create a service of type load balancer and expose load balancer's ip. You can also look into exposing service using ingress.

Comment: I would need to route TCP traffic.. so ingress may not work.. L4 load balacer is ideal, but thats restriction.. i so not have a Lb. And since it's within DMZ, i was planning to avoid lb also.

Comment: Could you attach the `yaml definition` of your `service` ? The documentation says: *"In the Service spec, externalIPs can be specified along with any of the ServiceTypes."* so in theory it should work with `nodePort` service if everything is configured properly. It also says: *"`externalIPs` are not managed by Kubernetes and are the responsibility of the cluster administrator."* First make sure it is available on a node level e.g. by running there `netcat` listening on some port and try to hit this `<external_ip>:port` from outside.

Comment: ---
## NodePort

apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: sample-app-nodeport-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: sample-app
  type: NodePort
  ports:  
  - name: http
    port: 80
    targetPort: sample-app
    nodePort: 30036
    protocol: TCP
  externalIPs:
    - 52.215.108.42


@mario  .. Unable to format.sorry

Comment: You can edit your question and post it there, keeping the original formatting (Ctrl + K on marked text).